# UIButton semanticContentAttribute property is forced RTL in Localization

Tags: swift, localization, arabic

I'm working on an app which supports two languages(English & Arabic). I have a `loginCViewController` in which I have a `UIButton and UITextField`. When I switch to `Arabic`, my `UIButton semanticContentAttribute` is forced `RightToLeft` which I don't want.

`Arabic`

[image]

`English`

[image]

This is what I have tried so far, but My UIButton still changes it's `semanticContentAttribute` from RightToLeft when switched to Arabic Language.

I want my `loginViewController` to look same for both languages.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        numberButton.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    }
```

I even tried it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` but still, same results.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        numberButton.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    }
```

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey may be this code will help you because it's working for me.

```
   UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
   let window = self.view.superview
   self.view.removeFromSuperview()
   window?.addSubview(self.view)
```

Comment: well it gives me what I want, but this disturbs my rest of the ViewControllers.

Comment: can you tell me where your view has disturb so may be i can help you

Comment: in every other ViewController of my App.

Comment: on other view you want to change same code 
 UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

Comment: if you can give me proper code then may be we will change that particular button.
Tell me one thing how to change left to right view in your code

Comment: if your textfield and country code is on view then create a outlet of that view and then paste that code and it will work for on that view 

      self.viewssss.semanticContentAttribute = your lanugage == arbic ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight

and this code work for me only for that particular view

Comment: Thankyou so much bro. :D This worked for me. 
myView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight